# Error In File "/usr/lib/python2.4/subprocess.py", line 542, in __init__

Tags: python, syntax-error, subprocess

```
import subprocess, sys, shlex

for i in range(n):
    node_id = "n" + str(i + 1)
    cmd = "x-terminal-emulator -e 'sudo python3.2 node.py " + str(n) + " " + node_id + "'"
    process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    #process.wait()

print (process.returncode)
```

When I execute this script, the is error is:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/subprocess.py", line 542, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/subprocess.py", line 975, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Check if there's no `node.py` file.

Comment: Or no `x-terminal-emulator` or no `python3.2` or no `sudo` (you could have a really messed up `PATH`, we have no idea).

Comment: i should installed ?

Comment: Can u give me ur Email Plz to contact You in private please , i have no idea about  x-terminal-emulator ....